# I can't understand the result of this $random(seed) code

Tags: verilog

```
module random;

 reg [31:0] addr;
 integer seed;

 initial begin
     seed = 5;
     $monitor("%t->%d", $time, addr);
     #30 $stop;
 end

 always #5 addr = $random(seed);

 endmodule
```

In this code, if I declare `seed` with `integer`, the `seed` value changes every #5. But, if I declare `seed` with `reg[3:0]`, the `seed` value is 5 continuously. I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Could you show the difference between the forms.

Comment: With `always #5 addr = $random(seed);` you call random every 5 timesteps and if random can update its seed that is why it would change every 5 timesteps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates a very small sample size (5).  You should generate more random numbers.  When I did so, I saw more than one value with `reg [3:0] seed;`.  Change `#30` to `#300`, for example.

When I use `reg [31:0] seed;`, I get the same type of distribution as when I use `integer`.  I don't see any explanation of this behavior in the IEEE Std 1800-2012 for `$random`, but section 20.15.2 "Distribution functions" mentions:

> For each system function, the seed argument is an inout argument; that
>   is, a value is passed to the function, and a different value is
>   returned. The system functions shall always return the same value
>   given the same seed.

You should see `seed` changing on every call.

```
$monitor("addr=%d seed=%d", addr, seed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you start using $urandom instead of $random. It makes it easy to control the seed from the command line without having to recompile, and you get better random stability as well.

The `seed` to $random is supposed to be at least a 32-bit integer (Although it is not explained in the LRM, the code for $random is in the append). A 32-bit seed does not mean you will get 2**32-1 random numbers. As you shorten the width of the seed, you shorten the number of random numbers that it takes to repeat the cycle of random numbers. By the time you get down to 4 bits, the probability that the cycle for a particular seed goes to 1 is pretty high.